Rails: Form that sets up default values for an object?
Say I have an object that has some attributes with default values. I set up the default values for these attributes at a model level like so...
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.name ||= "Player"
    self.level ||= 5
  end

I want to have a way for the user to set what the default values are though. The workflow would be the user would have an action to set their own defaults (in the view, this would be done via a form) and then these defaults would be used in the model method set_defaults, like so...
  def set_defaults
    self.name ||= user_default_for_name
    self.level ||= user_default_for_level
  end

I have thought about approaching this by making a "default" object in the code that the user "edits". Then, in the model method, the defaults will be set from the values in that object. But is there any better way of doing this?

In general I'm not a fan of callbacks to set default values for attributes. This is a very dated approach and can have wierd and unexpected side effects due to the timing issues.
If the default values are not part of the database schema (like booleans that default to false for example) but can be defined on the class level you can use the ActiveModel or ActiveRecord attributes API to set defaults.
attribute :level, :integer, default: 5

This is also an area where you could consider using the Form Object Pattern to avoid making your model into even more of god class.
Form Objects are classes that wrap a model for the purpose of handling user input.
class PlayerForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  
  attr_accessor :player
  attribute :level, :integer,  default: 5
  attribute :name,  :string,   default: "Player"
  
  # this lets the form object interact with Rails API's
  # for routing 
  delegate :to_model, :model_name, to: :player

  def initialize(**attributes)
    super  
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def save
    return false unless self.valid?
    @player.assign_attributes(level: level, name: name)
    @player.save   
  end
end

On the controller level we just swap out the Player class for the PlayerForm class:
class PlayerController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @player = PlayerForm.new
  end

  def create
    @player = PlayerForm.new(player_attributes)
    if @player.save 
      redirect_to @player
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end
end

While the immediate gains here can seem small now setting the defaults only happens when you actually want it - when populating a form and not every time the model is instanciated.

I have thought about approaching this by making a "default" object in the code that the user "edits". Then, in the model method, the defaults will be set from the values in that object. But is there any better way of doing this?

If you want the default values to be personizable by the users via the GUI you would create a model (and the related routes and controller) for that:
# rails g model UserDefault name:string level:integer
class UserDefault < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

You could then plug the user defaults model into the Form Object we created earlier:
class PlayerForm
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :player
  attribute :level, :integer
  attribute :name,  :string
  
  # this lets the form object interact with Rails API's
  # for routing 
  delegate :to_model, :model_name, to: :player

  def initalize(**attributes)
    super
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def save
    return false unless self.valid?
    @player.assign_attributes(level: level, name: name)
    @player.save   
  end

  def assign_user_defaults(defaults)
    assign_attributes(defaults.attributes.slice(:name, :level))
  end
end

class PlayerController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def new 
    @player = PlayerForm.new
    @player.assign_user_defaults(current_user.user_default) if current_user.user_default
  end

  def create
    @player = PlayerForm.new(player_attributes)
    if @player.save 
      redirect_to @player
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end
end

Here I'm making the assumption that there is an authentication system and some sort of method on the user that returns their preferred set of defaults.

you have to include ActiveModel::Model first, otherwise PlayerForm.new(level: 1) raises an error. also initialize.

Awesome answer - thank you Max! And Thank you Alex for the heads up too :)

Thanks @Alex for pointing for pointing that out.
